# COUNT(DISTINCT ...) in Slick

Tags: scala, slick

How to express COUNT(DISTINCT ...) in Slick?

I want to build an equivalent of this query:

```
sql"""select formatdatetime("timestamp",'yyyy.MM.dd'), count(distinct "order_id")
    from "sales" group by
    formatdatetime("timestamp",'yyyy.MM.dd')""".as[(String,Option[Int])]
```

I tried this:

```
val values = sales groupBy { entry =>
  formatDatetime(entry.timestamp, datetimeFormat)
} map { case(formattedDatetime, group) =>
  (formattedDatetime, group.distinctOn(_.orderId).length.?)
}
```

Which throws runtime exception:

```
[info]   slick.SlickTreeException: Cannot convert node to SQL Comprehension
[info] | Path s9._2 : Vector[t2<{s3: Int', s4: java.sql.Timestamp', s5: scala.math.BigDecimal', s6: java.sql.Timestamp', s7: String', s8: String'}>]
```

(I use H2)

Answer (score 1):

What definitely works / My best shot so far:

```
val countDistinctOrderId = SimpleExpression.nullary[Int] { queryBuilder =>
  import slick.util.MacroSupport._
  import queryBuilder._
  b"""count(distinct "order_id")"""
}
val values = sales groupBy { entry =>
  formatDatetime(entry.timestamp, datetimeFormat)
} map { case(formattedDatetime, group) =>
  (formattedDatetime, countDistinctOrderId.?)
}
```

Comment: Known issue https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/1760 - can use the deprecated `countDistinct` method.